# How to create a function that makes a button move down each time it's clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a function that makes a button go downward whenever it's clicked on.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def move_Button_Down_After_Each_CLick():
    b.place_forget()
    n=0
    m=0
    while n<=10:
        n+=1
        m+=5
        b.place(x= 10, y = 10+m)

b = Button(root, text="Delete me",  command=move_Button_Down_After_Each_CLick)
b.place(x = 0, y = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reseting `n` and `m` each time you run the method, so after your `while` loop they will always end up at the same value. You must declare them outside of your function, so that they can be added to each time the function is called (on click). In fact, I'm not really sure why you have two variables, and a loop, in this function at all. I believe what you are trying to do is this.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

n = 0
def move_Button_Down_After_Each_CLick():
    global n
    b.place_forget()  
    moveDist = 5  #Distance button will move down on each click
    n += moveDist
    b.place(x = 0, y = n)

b = Button(root, text="Delete me",  command=move_Button_Down_After_Each_CLick)
b.place(x = 0, y = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As far as I know, global variables cannot be set without first using `global` to import them into the functions scope.  Have you ran this code in Python 3 to ensure it works?  I imagine that `n += moveDist` fails upon clicking the button, even if fine when the script is initially ran.

Comment: Good point, I overlooked that. Edited to include global scope injection. Just tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite badly organized and you didn't give us any idea of your current thinking.  Along with that, your function to move the button down makes little to no sense and needs to be completely rewritten, I'd be interested why you thought loops were necessary to achieve your goal.  I don't say these things to be mean or discourage you, but simply  to stress the seriousness of your code's current quality.  Building a program much larger than this will be extremely difficult without proper organization and planning.

Here's the my code and then below I will explain my thought process:

```
from tkinter import *

#Definitions
window_w = 300
window_h = 200
button_x = 0
button_y = 0

#Functions
def move_button_down():
    global button_x, button_y, b

    if (button_y < window_h - 50):
        button_y = button_y + 10

    b.place_forget()        
    b.place(x = button_x, y = button_y)

#Main Code
root = Tk()
size = str(window_w) + "x" + str(window_h)
root.geometry(size)
root.resizable(1, 0)

b = Button(root, text="Delete me",  command=move_button_down)
b.place(x = button_x, y = button_y)
root.mainloop()
```

First of all, I started by separating your code into sections so that it's legible, then I define important variables to help keep our code organized and modular.  By defining the windows width and height in variables we can use that in code, and I also added the ability for your window to start a size with horizontal resize disabled (but not vertical in case you wish to know how to enable / disable both).  The x and y positions of the button are defined to and for larger programs you'll want to maintain a list of objects / arrays with the x, y, and potentially z values for all of your GUI components.

For your function, I both properly named it (I double capitalize by accident sometimes too but code quality is important, cough cough "CLick") and included the global variables (which you should have done previously with "b").  In addition to adding the correct functionality (`button_y = button_y + 10`) I also made sure the button couldn't go off the edge of the screen which is why it's always good to define your window size with variables.

For the main code nothing much has changed other than the name of the function and the window size additions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by passing the `Button` to the function and having the function use that to determine its current location.

Here's what I mean:

```
import tkinter as tk

def move_button_down_after_each_click(button):
    # Get the current position.
    current_x = int(button.place_info()['x'])
    current_y = int(button.place_info()['y'])
    # Move the widget.
    button.place(x=current_x, y=current_y+10)

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Delete me",
              command=lambda: move_button_down_after_each_click(b))
b.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Note, I left the `while` loop out of the function because it's not needed to move the button. If you were trying to animate the `Button`'s movement, then that's a differently different question...